# Trying to stop email alert on FAIL inside PHP script when a fail occurs.  

Tags: php, mysql, email, if-statement, exit

I just discovered that I'm still receiving an email EVEN when there is an error (reg_add_fail.php).  Is it possible to stop the script from emailing me IF the client is directed to reg_add_fail.php?  Confused...

I simplified the script to condense.

Many thanks.

Erik

```
<?

$to = 'newreg@41q.org';
$subject = 'New Homeless Connection';
$msg = "<html>
<head>
<title>New Homeless Connection</title>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\" border=\"1\" align=\"left\">
<tr>
<td align=\"left\" width=\"150px\">Registery No.:</td>
<td align=\"left\"> $reg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=\"left\">First Name:</td>
<td align=\"left\">$first_name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=\"left\">Connection Date:</td>
<td align=\"left\"$>$connect_date</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td align=\"left\" colspan=\"2\">http://www.41q.org/admin/</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
";

// Make sure to escape quotes

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Homeless' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$submit_date = date("m/d/y g:i A") ; 

$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add (submit_date, 
connect_date, 
reg, 
first_name, 
)

VALUES

('$submit_date',
'$_POST[connect_date]', 
'{$_POST[reg]}nv', 
'$_POST[first_name]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

if ($result) { 
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);  
$reg =          $_REQUEST['reg'] ; 
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name']; 
header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name)); 
} 
else { 
header("location: reg_add_fail.php"); 
exit(); // as sugested by John Conde
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `exit()` after the redirect

```
header("location: reg_add_fail.php");
exit();
```

Just because you call `header()` doesn't mean the script stops executing immediately. Calling `exit()` will.

Comment: I tried and I still got the email.  Maybe if I move this section to the top of the script?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the PHP mail() function is being called outside the IF statement, so, you always get the email.

To send the email only when the query runs without errors, place the mail() inside the if statement!

**PHP**

```
if ($result) { 
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);  
  $reg =          $_REQUEST['reg'] ; 
  $first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name']; 
  header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name)); 
} 
else { 
  header("location: reg_add_fail.php"); 
  exit(); // as sugested by John Conde
}
```

**EDITED TO SHOW THE ENTIRE CODE:**

```
<?php

// Email Recipient
$to = 'newreg@41q.org';

// Email Subject
$subject = 'New Homeless Connection';


// Email Message
$msg = '
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New Homeless Connection</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1" align="left">
      <tr>
        <td align="left" width="150px">Registery No.:</td>
        <td align="left">'.$reg.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">First Name:</td>
        <td align="left">'.$first_name.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Connection Date:</td>
        <td align="left">'.$connect_date.'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="2"><a href="http://www.41q.org/admin/" title="">http://www.41q.org/admin/</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>';

// Email Headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Homeless' . "\r\n";


date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$submit_date = date("m/d/y g:i A") ; 

// Prepare Database Query
$order = "
  INSERT INTO reg_add (
    submit_date,
    connect_date,
    reg,
    first_name
  )
  VALUES (
    '".$submit_date."',
    '".$_POST['connect_date']."', 
    '".$_POST['reg']."nv', 
    '".$_POST['first_name']."'
  )";

// Query Database
$result = mysql_query($order);


// Check If the result is valid
if ($result) { 

  // send email
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);  

  // prepare and direct the user to the reg_add_success Page
  $reg =          $_REQUEST['reg'] ; 
  $first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name']; 
  header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name)); 

} 
else {

  // send the user to the reg_add_fail Page
  header("location: reg_add_fail.php"); 

  // exit from the script
  exit();

}

?>
```

Comment: Is there a particular location where I should place this?

Comment: I updated the script with your change in this post.  I'm still getting the emails when I go to fail.  Very strange.

Comment: I tried moving this section to the top of the script and it worked, but NOW I don't receive any emails even on good ones.

Comment: Don't leave me hanging now.  :-)

Comment: Sorry Erik, a man need to sleep :)  Just remove the mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers); that you have after your $headers variable.

Comment: @Erik, I just edited the answer to include your entire code, I placed some comments and made some code cleaning :)